# Node.JS: Can't figure out what's causing a memory leak (heap space)

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory, memory-leaks

After a few hours of running my node.js server, I get a "javascript heap space out of memory" error. I could increase it but the memory keeps going up so I don't think increasing the heap size will solve this.

I'm trying to use the chrome dev tools to figure out:

- What file this is occurring on
- What object/variable this is occurring on

But the chrome dev tools are so hard to read. I believe there's a memory leak somewhere in my program because the amount of memory keeps going up over time.

Is there a way to figure out what lines of code are possibly causing a memory leak or what objects are getting filled up with memory using the chrome dev tools?

When I take a heap snapshot using chrome dev tools, I look at the objects with the most memory but I can't figure out what objects these are in my code, there's no names of the variables or anything.

Comment: If it's your node app that's causing the error I don't think Chrome is going to help debug it. Is the error in the browser console, or the terminal running your node application? What does you client do? We can't really help unless you debug parts of it, and then post a [mcve] here for us to look at.

Comment: The error appeared in the terminal, I'm using node.js on Windows. My client basically calls API calls every 30 seconds based on API endpoint IDs in a local .json file (loaded once and stored in a global variable called "db") or so, uses the data it downloaded, calculates a few things and saves those calculations in the db object and then converst the db object into a JSON string and saves it in a .json file on each API fetch. I use promises to ensure all API calls were executed and resolve them.